# how to specify a var field in mongodb find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

In mongodb, I want to find a document which exist a field returned by a function.
for  example:

```
var field = func()
var cur = db.test.find({field:{$exists:1}}).limit(1)
```

Mongodb to find a document has a field named "field", but I want to find a document has a field named the value of the var "field". what shoud I do. Thankd you very much.

Comment: let's say my collection has documents where I am saving Names of students so you want to search for a specific name's existence in the collection, right?

Comment: No. Some students has the field "name", some students has the field "age". Then I set a variable named "myfield", I want to find the students which has the field of the value of `myfield`. If I set myfield='name', the result is the students has the field name. If I set myfield='age', the result is the students has the field age.

Comment: That find is just json, so why can't your function just return the json (including whatever field name you'd like?

Comment: Check the answer. Works on shell.

Comment: thanks @bri. It solved my questions. Also thank you Gandalf the White.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
db.CollectionName.find({},{FieldName:1})
```

in case I want to have results of students who have field named age in their document.

```
db.CollectionName.find({},{age:1}) // will result all documents with age in their field
```